# Detect space before a footnote

Tags: spacing, footnotes, proofreading

I'm in the middle of proofreading TeX source for a book, and have found a couple of places where a stray space has slipped through before a footnote mark. Is there any automated way of scanning TeX source to detect this?

Comment: I'd like to add a 'proofreading' tag here, if no one objected. I think there is a class of otherwise disparate activities  which naturally fall under that tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're running linux or OSX or cygwin under Windows, you can use

```
grep -n '\([[:space:]]\|^\)\\footnote' file.tex
```

in a terminal. This command outputs each line of file `file.tex` (prefixed with line number) that contains `\footnote` preceded by a space (any type of space) or at the beginning of a line.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends whether you are proofreading the PDF or the *.tex source. While there may be a possibility to search via »regular expressions« through a PDF looking for footnote numbers, I have no idea how to do that.

But for the *.tex source in the editor there should be a very easy solution: All editors I know provide a funcitionality called »search and replace«. You just have to search for `_\footnote{`  and replace that by `\footnote{` .

---

Edit: As serveral comments demand to be as precise as possible, I admit that this would be usefull. So I correct: "`_`" meant a whitespace and certainly it would be a good idea to search and replace two leading whitespaces before a footnote, as well.

Comment: Does '_' match against whitespace in standard r.e.s?

Comment: Nitpick: that would not work for `this  \footnote{\dots}` that is preceded by two spaces. Tab characters also pose a problem, as do footnote commands at the beginning of a line.